# Regular expression in file path

Tags: etl, talend, file-watcher

I need to enter regular expression in a file path name inside tfileinputdelimited

I have a file watcher that is looking inside a directory for new files to be added. I want the new files have similar word for example file 1 is called apple1.csv and the other file that will be added at another time is called apple2.csv I want a way in order to tell talend to extract the file that contains the word apple, regardless of whats before or after.

Right now I have:

twaitforfile -> tflowtoiterate  -> tfileinputdelimited -> tmap -> tdboutput

I believe tfileinputdelimited should have a regular expression as right now I selected a specific file

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the twaitforfile component, in the File Mask field specify the following: "*apple*.csv". This should grab only the files that have the word apple in them.

[image]

To dynamically grab these files base on their file names through tfileinputdelimited, you can use the FILENAME global parameter of the twaitforfile to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Im still having the problem that it doesn't add to the database the new file apple2.csv. right now I have twaitforfile -> tflowtoiterate -> tfileinputdelimited -> tmap -> tdboutput . I am thinking maybe because I have tfileinputdelimited which chooses a specific file .. in this case apple1.csv , keeping apple2.csv not loaded. Could you please tell me if my order is correct otherwise how can I map a schema from twaitforfile right away

Comment: Another followup: what if I need to make the file watcher also look into subdirectories. I clicked on that checkbox on the twaitforfile, however, although it is detected, it gives an error in mapping, I believe also due to something with tfileinputdelimited. How can I make it look into the directory and also subdirectory

Comment: It should work fine. Are you sure you don't have any errors in your CSV? What errors are you getting?

Comment: it gives the file path along to the file name that is inside the subdirectory.. then it says this : (No such file or directory)

Comment: ok so I figured out something. If I take a file from the main directory and copy it to the sub directory then it works. However, if I create a csv file and save it directly inside the subdirectory it doesn't. But I have no clue why

Comment: In that case we need to make it more dynamic, it the tFileInputDelimited set the File Name/Stream as (String)globalMap.get("tWaitForFile_1_CREATED_FILE") so that it can grab the entire path of the file and accepts subdirectories

Comment: Nope this didn't work, right now its not accepting from both the directory and subdirectory. err: path/applycopy.csv (No such file or directory)

Comment: Can you attach an image of your Job, the details of the twaitforfile and tfileinputdelimited?

Comment: I have added the images in the question above

Comment: tfileInputDelimited file stream should be equal to (String)globalMap.get("tWaitForFile_1_CREATED_FILE") only. Remove the static part that is at the start.

Comment: YES that is perfect. I Really appreciate your help.. this is really valuable.. thanks alot

Comment: Hello I have another problem, and I thought you could be able to help me due to your expertise in talend and because your suggestion last time helped me a lot.

Comment: I need to send an email at the end of ETL process. However I need the email address to be extracted from the tfileinputdelimited.Right now I have twaitforfile -> tflowtoiterate -> tfileinputdelimited -> tmap_1 -> tbdoutput ->tsendemail What I want to do is get the email from the tfileinputdelimited, I dont know the email ahead of time thats why I can't add a predefined list. It all depends on the new file added and detected by the file watcher. I can't also add global variable to tfileinputdelimited since the tfileinputdelimited is connected to other things from both sides as shown above